# Was Haven rid of the Troubles after the events of the series finale?

Tags: haven

In the last scenes of the series finale, we see that

> Although "trouble aether" is seen apparently drawn out of residents of Haven, Dwight is re-united with his dead daughter and, (as explained by Vince and Croatoan) Audrey comes back as Paige to be re-united (in a sense) with Nathan. Both of these phenomena had to be the result of troubles, didn't they?

So could Haven really be rid of the troubles

> as promised by "the controller", did they continue in some other form, or
>  was it an intentionally ambiguous ending?

Comment: Seems not very much haven viewers here. No answer and no comment to any haven question. I think that haven got rid of the troubles. The fact that Dwights daugther did not disappear was due to "believing" she was real. And the return of Audrey had nothing to do with troubles in the past. So, no aether, no troubles, a new barn, a new barn controller, a "good" croatoan and a returned Audrey (this time forever?)